# K8s Operator listen to secret change with event filter

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets, kubebuilder

We have created a few month ago controller which runs great using kubebuilder.

Few weeks ago we added a “listener” to a secret which when the secret is changing (secret properties)
The **reconcile** should be invoked, the problem is that it is **sometimes working** and **sometimes not**, (you change the secret apply it and the reconcile doesn’t happens) , we are doing it for the exact **same** secret file.

We tried few days to find the root cause without success, (we change the `k8s.io/client-go v0.23.4` and also to `v0.22.3` and now  `v0.22.1` that is only working.
Any idea what the issue could be? any hint will be helpful. or Any other way to do it that we can try out.

```
func (r *vtsReconciler) SetupWithManager(mgr ctrl.Manager) error {
    manager := ctrl.NewControllerManagedBy(mgr).
        For(&vts.str).
        WithEventFilter(predicate.Or(predicate.AnnotationChangedPredicate{}))
    manager = manager.Watches(&source.Kind{Type: &v1.Secret{}}, handler.EnqueueRequestsFromMapFunc(func(a client.Object) []reconcile.Request {
        return r.SecretRequests.SecretFinder(a.GetName())
    }))
    return manager.Complete(r)
}



func (secm *SecretMapper) SecretFinder(name string) []reconcile.Request {
    v := cli.ObjectKey{Name: name}
    return secm.SecMap[v.String()]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely the issue is that the `WithEventFIlter` applies to all watched objects by the controller. The generation is auto-incremented for CRDs, but this doesn't hold for all resource types.

From the GenerationChangedPredicate docs:

```
// Caveats:
//
// * The assumption that the Generation is incremented only on writing to the spec does not hold for all APIs.
// E.g For Deployment objects the Generation is also incremented on writes to the metadata.annotations field.
// For object types other than CustomResources be sure to verify which fields will trigger a Generation increment when they are written to.
```

You can check this by creating a secret / updating a secret you will see that there is no generation set (at least not on my local k3d cluster).

Most likely it works for the creation as initially the controller will sync existing resources with the cluster.

To solve it you can use:

```golang
func (r *vtsReconciler) SetupWithManager(mgr ctrl.Manager) error {
    manager := ctrl.NewControllerManagedBy(mgr).
        For(&vts.str, WithPredicates(predicate.Or(predicate.GenerationChangedPredicate{}, predicate.AnnotationChangedPredicate{}))).
    manager = manager.Watches(&source.Kind{Type: &v1.Secret{}}, handler.EnqueueRequestsFromMapFunc(func(a client.Object) []reconcile.Request {
        return r.SecretRequests.FindForSecret(a.GetNamespace(), a.GetName())
    }))
    return manager.Complete(r)
}
```

which should apply the predicates only to your custom resource.

Comment: Thanks, im trying it now, but there is no `WithPredicates` , any idea?

Comment: I've replace the `withEventFilter` to use `withPredicates` and the code doesnt compile and didnt find the `WithPredicates` , what am I missing here?

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/controller-runtime/blob/master/pkg/builder/options.go#L48 I guess it depends on your controller-runtime version

Comment: So, should I add `builder.WithPredicates`? as im not using the `builder` on my code

Comment: Yeah indeed, you can import the builder package. I am not sure if controller-runtime has an alias for it, I don't think it does (see: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/controller-runtime/blob/v0.11.1/alias.go). Once you do that, the predicates should only apply to the specific resource.

Comment: I tried it out and it doesnt works, any other idea?

Comment: Can you include the code of r.SecretRequests.FindForSecret? And the updated code.

Comment: I've added it to the post

Comment: Are you sure your secret map is kept properly up to date? Normally you would just use the go-client to request the secret (given that the go-client already performs caching).